# Click inside iframe open event in parent (same domains)?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to use .slideToggle to open event details from my calendar (in iframe) My code is:

```
<div id="clickme"><iframe id="frame" src="index.php?option=com_jevents&view=month&task=month.calendar&template=ja_purity" mce_src="index.php?option=com_jevents&view=month&task=month.calendar&template=ja_purity">Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe></div>

<div id="book" style="display:none;"><iframe name="details" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<script>
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
```

You can see how it works here: [wisko.pl](http://wisko.pl/)
Now slide work only when i click iframe border. I'd like it to open when i click on event in calendar. Is it possible? How can i use .click function to check divs inside iframe?

#### Update:

Thank you. Still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? My main document has:

```
<script>
function showevent(){
$('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
</script>
```

In Iframe i put:

```
<script>
$('#eventstyle').click(function() {
document.parent.showevent();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I took a look at wisko.pl and I don't see jquery included there.

Answer (score 0):

in main document:

```
function showevent(){
$('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

inside iframe:

```
window.parent.showevent();
```

running this inside iframe will cause the function to run. And you have to catch the click event inside the iframe - you can't otherwise.

edit:
 1. My bad: i put document.parent here instead of window.parent - fixed now
 2. Your bad: when you use jquery to assign click events to things, you have to be sure these things already exist. all jquery code should be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code here*/});` That's why it had no chance of working for you.

Comment: I'm still having problems making this work. I described everything below.